# Can I use the javascript interpreter inside Firefox as a js shell?

Tags: javascript, shell, firefox

I would like to start coding with JS by writing more evolved versions of my bash scripts, therefore I would like to take actions like download a package, unpack it, move between folders, execute shell/system commands, etc etc ... .

Now I would like to use the integrated shell interpreter inside Firefox but without any DOM related features and basically it should be as "dry" as possible so I can get a fairly standard JS shell and also a more simple set of APIs.

Someone knows if I can do that ?

Comment: No.  The browser has extremely limited access to the platform. You can, however, use Node.js.

Comment: It's not Firefox, but how about [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)? You might be interested in using it like [this](http://gwb.blob.core.windows.net/shaunxu/Windows-Live-Writer/Node.js-A.js-with-Windows-and-SQL-Server_92CC/image_18.png). Edit: Ninja'd.

Comment: @Pointy and Spooky, I'm trying to start with the _right foot_, meaning with a standard and portable approach, `node.js` doesn't look standard; I don't if this kind of functionalities are part of the JS standard library tho .

Comment: @user2485710 - As far as I know, there are no formal standards for a lot of things that you want in a JS shell (like launching other apps, collecting results from those apps, setting environment variables, reading environment variables, etc...).  Is there some specific standard implementation you think you're looking for?  From the standpoint of lots of people using it and a vibrant third party community, node is way more "standard" than anything else at this point.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a "standard library", all APIs that you can access and that are not specified in ECMAScript specifications are environment dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) and [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell) which are both related to the Mozilla JS engine.  A list of other JS shells is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Shells) which include things like Node (based on the Chrome V8 engine).

I'm personally using Node just because the level of 3rd party support for Node modules seems to have really taken off in the last couple years and you can also use it for web server development if you so choose and it all runs on many platforms.

Comment: so there is no standard library for the kind of functions I'm using ? It seems that in the JS world you are supposed to stick with 1 side/library and you can't really write portable code with some sort of standard library .

Comment: @user2485710 - you can write portable code in node (multiple Unix, Mac, Windows) as the library of things that come with it is pretty rich and comes with cross platform implementations.  There are always some issues with portability, when you get into the fringes of how some OSes just do things differently (like reporting memory usage of processes), but you can usually avoid those fringes if you want to and they are usually called out in the doc.  I don't know about the portability of the others.  There is no standards body curated "standard" that I know of for functionality in a JS shell.

Comment: @user2485710 - perhaps you should describe what you mean by "standard library"?

Comment: Well with "standard" I mean that I can have a function that has the same semantic, signature and functionality in any possible implementation; for example if I use the functions `getViaHTTP` and `unpackTar` under Linux with nodejs I would like to get the same behaviour under Windows with another JS shell or inside a web browser .

Comment: by the way, `nodejs` works both offline and online ? in a JS shell and in a browser ?

Comment: You can't really ask for universally equal behaviour inside a shell and a web browser, that's fundamentally different environments. There is Node, and there is Browserify - but Browserify won't make it possible to read/write files inside the browser, for good reasons. You should read up on what they both can and can't do.

Comment: nodejs has nothing to do with a browser.  It is a stand-alone execution environment and you can do local things or networked things - your choice.

Comment: Right now, you can't switch JS shells and expect the same behavior in all.  There is no defined standard beyond the JS language that applies here.  You can switch platforms with the same shell and have the same behavior (within a few limits of platform capabilities).  In nodejs, you can make a bunch of http requests, collect the data, process it and write it all to a local file and do that exactly the same on any of the major OS platforms.

Comment: ok, last thing, I found that the `tar` library is an extra package with `nodejs` https://www.npmjs.org/package/tar . Can I use that package and include it locally so that if I redistribute my sources I can run that without downloading anything extra beside the nodejs interpreter ?

Comment: @user2485710 - In the nodejs world, you would typically package your app using the npm package manager.  This will create a package description which includes which outside modules (and which version of those modules) are required with your app.  Then, in the process of installing your app, npm would automatically retrieve the right version of the other modules your app depends upon.  Node modules generally (or perhaps always) have a license file (usually one of the open source flavors).  That tar module uses the BSD license.